# How to unescape special characters in Rust?

Tags: rust, str-replace, regexp-replace, replaceall

For example, if you have escaped string like
`Hello wo\\\\rld.txt` 
you want to unescape it and make it, `Hello wo\\rld.txt`

essentially making,
`\\ -> \,  \\r -> \r,  \\n -> \n`,
etc

I tried doing string replace like:

`out = out.replace("\\", "\");` 
but that is syntax error

Comment: I never used it but... _there is crate for that!_ Meet [unescape](https://crates.io/crates/unescape).

Answer (score 0):

You still have to escape every `\` in your string literals i.e. `out = out.replace("\\\\", "\\");`

Comment: If I replace "\\\\" with "\\" then,

hello wo\\\\rld.txt
will become: hello wo\\rld

and in next step when I unescape \\r -> \r it will become, \r. This is incorrect.
We have to preserve \\r

Comment: Or avoid any escapes in literals by using raw literals:`out = out.replace(r"\\", r"\");`